# DownForEveryoneOrJustMe.com for generic sockets

Tags: network-monitor

I'm trying to set up a POP/SMTP email address on my Android device. However, the SMTP server is currently down, so I am currently stuck at the end of the setup process.

*Down For Everyone Or Just Me* will check HTTP servers, but I would like to have the same service for a generic socket, or, at least, the SMTP port of the SMTP server I need to use.

What I'm looking for:

- should try and open a socket, or, at least, an ICMP ping
- should keep trying until it succeeds (or, at least, it doesn't time out)
- should notify me when it finally succeeds

Non-goals:

- It doesn't have to be hosted by a third party. I'm not so much interested in knowing people on the other end of the world can set up the email address, I just want to know when *I* can do that.
- It doesn't have to be a standalone program. A very tiny shell script is fine, too.

**Note**: I have access to all platforms with the exceptions of OS X and iOS.

Comment: You would probably have to roll your own to find something that will keep trying a connection to a particular port, at least, it's not something seen as an option on a third party hosted site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [MXToolbox's SMTP checker](http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx). It's not a generic service that can check any port but it will check whether or not an SMTP server is listening and whether it can be connected to.

Here's some details:

- It's a webapp hosted on mxtoolbox.com available via a web browser
- It won't keep automatically trying until you cancel it, you'll need to manually retry
- It will clearly state once it does finally connect (or tell you what happened if it doesn't)

[image]